# Ubercart custom price, multiply price by user entered value

Tags: attributes, ubercart

I have an ubercart product with multiple options that need to be charged per person.  I've created an attribute called `Number of People` with a select box for numbers 20-40.

I need to multiply

```
(the price after the addition of the selected options) * Number of People
```

I am using Ubercart Custom Price which allows me to do the necessary math but I am not sure how to access the user selected value of `Number of People`.

So basically I need:

```
$item->price = $item->price * ['number_of_people']
```

I don't see anyway to access the Number of People from the $item object. Any Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `uc_attribute_tokens` module to get the value of the attribute "Number of People" on the calculation, both modules integrate. Check the *README.txt* file on the module for the token you need to use, it will be something like: `[number of people]`.

Comment: You are correct, I probably should have mentioned I was using drupal 7, ubercart 3.  I actually scrapped the entire site in favor of Drupal 6, at least until important modules like this one are ported.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what my calculation ended up looking like:

$item->price *= '[people]';
or
$item->price = $item->price * '[people]';

those single quotes are important, I saw no mention of them in any of the attribute_tokens_module documentation or examples, but without them i kept getting the error, ...unexpected '[' in...